# AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'ok' when using 'requests' inside a function

Tags: python

I am trying to grab match information from opendota.com API, but when I try with this code I get the following error:

```
import requests, json, time, os

#Download games
def get_match_by_id(match_id):
  m_id = str(match_id)
  #fetch match data
  requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/" + m_id)
  if requests.ok:
    print("GET:", m_id)
    data = requests.json()
    #save the match data
    file = open("download" + os.sep + m_id + '_data.json', 'w')
    json.dump(data, file)
    file.close()

match_id = 6727193237
match_id = 6757193237
for i in range(0, 5000):
  get_match_by_id(match_id + 1)
  time.sleep(2)



AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'ok'
```

Can anybody help me figure out the reason for this? I tried to lookup various other questions similar but none of those uses 'ok' as method

Comment: i think you meant requests.Response.ok

Comment: You're treating the module as if it was the object the get method returned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating the `requests` module as having the response returned from the request you sent with `requests.get()`. It doesn't have that information, which will cause unexpected behaviour. Instead, you need to assign the return value to a variable and use that to check the response.

```py
def get_match_by_id(match_id):
  m_id = str(match_id)
  response = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/" + m_id)
  if response.ok:
    print("GET:", m_id)
    data = response.json()
    with open("download" + os.sep + m_id + '_data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure how to do this! Working on the new problem that popped up now